# King and short rook checkmate

Tags: checkmate, chess-variants, rook-endgame, unorthodox-pieces

Suppose White has a king and a range-x rook and black has a bare king on a chessboard with dimensions y times y.
What is the minimum value of x such that for all sufficiently large y, White, moving first, can force a win no matter where the pieces are initially placed? Passing is not allowed and stalemate is a draw.

Comment: 50 move rule in force?

Comment: I am pretty sure x=5 is enough and x=3 is too weak. x=4 is most likely the border case...

Comment: @IanBush : certainly not, otherwise there is no solution...

Comment: @Evargalo Well x=8;y=8 certainly has a solution with the 50 move rule in force - if it does apply it "just" make the problem more complex.

Comment: @IanBush : sure, but there is no x *such that for all sufficiently large y, White, moving first, can force a win no matter where the pieces are initially placed* if the 50 moves rules applies. (just place the bK 50*x files away from the rook and there won't even be a *check*). Anyway, the 50 moves never applies in fairy chess problems...

Comment: To clarify, 50-move rule not used, threefold repetition used.
Also, I agree that x=5 is enough.